# Cannot read an XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an  XML file: Customer.xml [has content below: file attached download click here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=44802984355639259715)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><msg:Msg xsi:schemaLocation="http://Epicor.com/Message/2.0 http://scshost/schemas/epicor/ScalaMessage.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:msg="http://Epicor.com/Message/2.0"><msg:Hdr><msg:Ctrl><msg:MsgID></msg:MsgID></msg:Ctrl><msg:Sender><msg:Name></msg:Name><msg:Subname></msg:Subname></msg:Sender><msg:Logon></msg:Logon></msg:Hdr><msg:Body><msg:Req msg-type="Out_track" action="Out"><msg:Dta><tns:UpdateRequest xmlns:msg="http://Epicor.com/InternalMessage/1.1" xmlns:tns="http://www.epicor.com/Mfg/UpdateRequest"><ds><CustomerDataSet><Customer><Company>01</Company><CustID>NT00001318</CustID><CustNum>2844</CustNum><Name>NHA THUOC PHONG KHAM HOANG DAT</Name><Address1>Xuân Sơn, Trung Giã</Address1><Address2></Address2><Address3>Sóc Sơn</Address3><City>Hà Nội</City><State></State><Zip></Zip><Country>Việt Nam</Country><ResaleID>xxxxxxxxxx</ResaleID><SalesRepCode></SalesRepCode><TerritoryID>HN</TerritoryID><ShipToNum>NT00001318-01</ShipToNum><TermsCode>COD</TermsCode><ShipViaCode></ShipViaCode><PrintStatements>true</PrintStatements><PrintLabels>true</PrintLabels><PrintAck>true</PrintAck><FinCharges>true</FinCharges><CreditHold>false</CreditHold><GroupCode>CLI</GroupCode><DiscountPercent>0</DiscountPercent><PrimPCon>0</PrimPCon><PrimBCon>0</PrimBCon><PrimSCon>0</PrimSCon><Comment></Comment><EstDate/><FaxNum></FaxNum><PhoneNum></PhoneNum><TaxExempt></TaxExempt><MarkUpID></MarkUpID><BillDay>0</BillDay><OneInvPerPS>true</OneInvPerPS><DefaultFOB></DefaultFOB><CreditIncludeOrders>true</CreditIncludeOrders><CreditReviewDate/><CreditHoldDate/><CreditHoldSource>MANUAL</CreditHoldSource><CreditClearUserID></CreditClearUserID><CreditClearDate/><CreditClearTime></CreditClearTime><EDICode></EDICode><Character01></Character01><Character02></Character02><Character03></Character03><Character04></Character04><Character05></Character05><Character06></Character06><Character07></Character07><Character08></Character08><Character09></Character09><Character10></Character10><Number01>0</Number01><Number02>0</Number02><Number03>0</Number03><Number04>0</Number04><Number05>0</Number05><Number06>0</Number06><Number07>0</Number07><Number08>0</Number08><Number09>0</Number09><Number10>0</Number10><Date01/><Date02/><Date03/><Date04/><Date05/><CheckBox01>true</CheckBox01><CheckBox02>false</CheckBox02><CheckBox03>true</CheckBox03><CheckBox04>false</CheckBox04><CheckBox05>false</CheckBox05><CurrencyCode>VND</CurrencyCode><CountryNum>28</CountryNum><LangNameID></LangNameID><BorderCrossing></BorderCrossing><FormatStr></FormatStr><BTName></BTName><BTAddress1></BTAddress1><BTAddress2></BTAddress2><BTAddress3></BTAddress3><BTCity></BTCity><BTState></BTState><BTZip></BTZip><BTCountryNum>0</BTCountryNum><BTCountry></BTCountry><BTPhoneNum></BTPhoneNum><BTFaxNum></BTFaxNum><BTFormatStr></BTFormatStr><ParentCustNum>0</ParentCustNum><TaxRegionCode>VATD</TaxRegionCode><ICCust>false</ICCust><ContBillDay>1</ContBillDay><EMailAddress></EMailAddress><ShippingQualifier></ShippingQualifier><AllocPriorityCode></AllocPriorityCode><ReservePriorityCode></ReservePriorityCode><LinkPortNum>0</LinkPortNum><WebCustomer>false</WebCustomer><CustomerType>CUS</CustomerType><NoContact>false</NoContact><TerritoryLock>false</TerritoryLock><CustURL></CustURL><PendingTerritoryID></PendingTerritoryID><ExtID></ExtID><ConsolidateSO>false</ConsolidateSO><Bill-Frequency>W</Bill-Frequency><CreditIncludePI>false</CreditIncludePI><GlobalCust>false</GlobalCust><ICTrader>false</ICTrader><TaxAuthorityCode></TaxAuthorityCode><ExternalDeliveryNote>false</ExternalDeliveryNote><GlobalCredIncOrd>true</GlobalCredIncOrd><GlobalCredIncPI>false</GlobalCredIncPI><GlobalCurrencyCode></GlobalCurrencyCode><ExternalID></ExternalID><GlobalCreditHold></GlobalCreditHold><GlobalLock>false</GlobalLock><CheckDuplicatePO>false</CheckDuplicatePO><CreditLimit>0</CreditLimit><CustPILimit>0</CustPILimit><GlobalCreditLimit>0</GlobalCreditLimit><GlobalPILimit>0</GlobalPILimit><DocGlobalCreditLimit>0</DocGlobalCreditLimit><DocGlobalPILimit>0</DocGlobalPILimit><RfqAttachAllow>false</RfqAttachAllow><DiscountQualifier>ADD</DiscountQualifier><Number11>0</Number11><Number12>0</Number12><Number13>0</Number13><Number14>0</Number14><Number15>0</Number15><Number16>0</Number16><Number17>0</Number17><Number18>0</Number18><Number19>0</Number19><Number20>0</Number20><Date06/><Date07/><Date08/><Date09/><Date10/><Date11/><Date12/><Date13/><Date14/><Date15/><Date16/><Date17/><Date18/><Date19/><Date20/><CheckBox06>false</CheckBox06><CheckBox07>false</CheckBox07><CheckBox08>false</CheckBox08><CheckBox09>false</CheckBox09><CheckBox10>false</CheckBox10><CheckBox11>false</CheckBox11><CheckBox12>false</CheckBox12><CheckBox13>false</CheckBox13><CheckBox14>false</CheckBox14><CheckBox15>false</CheckBox15><CheckBox16>false</CheckBox16><CheckBox17>false</CheckBox17><CheckBox18>false</CheckBox18><CheckBox19>false</CheckBox19><CheckBox20>false</CheckBox20><ShortChar01>NTPKHDAT</ShortChar01><ShortChar02>SOCSON.HN</ShortChar02><ShortChar03>PRCLIN</ShortChar03><ShortChar04></ShortChar04><ShortChar05></ShortChar05><ShortChar06></ShortChar06><ShortChar07>SM</ShortChar07><ShortChar08></ShortChar08><ShortChar09></ShortChar09><ShortChar10></ShortChar10><AllowAltBillTo>false</AllowAltBillTo><DemandDeliveryDays>0</DemandDeliveryDays><DemandDateType>S</DemandDateType><DemandAddLeadTime>0</DemandAddLeadTime><DemandAddAction>B</DemandAddAction><DemandChangeLeadTime>0</DemandChangeLeadTime><DemandChangeAction>B</DemandChangeAction><DemandCancelLeadTime>0</DemandCancelLeadTime><DemandCancelAction>B</DemandCancelAction><DemandNewLineLeadTime>0</DemandNewLineLeadTime><DemandNewLineAction>B</DemandNewLineAction><DemandQtyChangeLeadTime>0</DemandQtyChangeLeadTime><DemandQtyChangeAction>B</DemandQtyChangeAction><DemandChangeDateLeadTime>0</DemandChangeDateLeadTime><DemandChangeDateAction>B</DemandChangeDateAction><TradingPartnerName></TradingPartnerName><ResDelivery>false</ResDelivery><SatDelivery>false</SatDelivery><SatPickup>false</SatPickup><Hazmat>false</Hazmat><DocOnly>false</DocOnly><RefNotes></RefNotes><ApplyChrg>false</ApplyChrg><ChrgAmount>0</ChrgAmount><COD>false</COD><CODFreight>false</CODFreight><CODCheck>false</CODCheck><CODAmount>0</CODAmount><GroundType></GroundType><NotifyFlag>false</NotifyFlag><NotifyEMail></NotifyEMail><DeclaredIns>false</DeclaredIns><DeclaredAmt>0</DeclaredAmt><PeriodicityCode>0</PeriodicityCode><ServSignature>false</ServSignature><ServAlert>false</ServAlert><ServHomeDel>false</ServHomeDel><DeliveryType></DeliveryType><ServDeliveryDate/><ServPhone></ServPhone><ServInstruct></ServInstruct><ServRelease>false</ServRelease><ServAuthNum></ServAuthNum><ServRef1></ServRef1><ServRef2></ServRef2><ServRef3></ServRef3><ServRef4></ServRef4><ServRef5></ServRef5><EarlyBuffer>0</EarlyBuffer><LateBuffer>0</LateBuffer><DemandUnitPriceDiff>false</DemandUnitPriceDiff><DemandUnitPriceDiffAction>B</DemandUnitPriceDiffAction><ExcFromVal>false</ExcFromVal><AddressVal>false</AddressVal><RebateVendorNum>0</RebateVendorNum><RebateForm></RebateForm><CreditCardOrder>false</CreditCardOrder><DemandCheckForPart>false</DemandCheckForPart><DemandCheckForPartAction>B</DemandCheckForPartAction><ChangedBy>nguyennk</ChangedBy><ChangeDate>2015-05-07T00:00:00</ChangeDate><ChangeTime>38591</ChangeTime><ChargeCode></ChargeCode><IndividualPackIDs>false</IndividualPackIDs><IntrntlShip>false</IntrntlShip><CertOfOrigin>false</CertOfOrigin><CommercialInvoice>false</CommercialInvoice><ShipExprtDeclartn>false</ShipExprtDeclartn><LetterOfInstr>false</LetterOfInstr><FFID></FFID><FFCompName></FFCompName><FFAddress1></FFAddress1><FFAddress2></FFAddress2><FFAddress3></FFAddress3><FFCity></FFCity><FFState></FFState><FFZip></FFZip><FFCountry></FFCountry><FFCountryNum>0</FFCountryNum><FFPhoneNum></FFPhoneNum><NonStdPkg>false</NonStdPkg><DeliveryConf>1</DeliveryConf><AddlHdlgFlag>false</AddlHdlgFlag><UPSQuantumView>false</UPSQuantumView><UPSQVShipFromName></UPSQVShipFromName><UPSQVMemo></UPSQVMemo><UPSQVEmailType></UPSQVEmailType><FFContact></FFContact><ETCAddrChg>false</ETCAddrChg><TaxRoundRule>0</TaxRoundRule><TaxMethod>L</TaxMethod><SysRowID>9ac2de6d-d796-09ae-e311-5baf8a8712ec</SysRowID><SysRevID>151270000</SysRevID><ValidPayer>true</ValidPayer><ValidSoldTo>true</ValidSoldTo><ValidShipTo>true</ValidShipTo><OverrideRlsClass>false</OverrideRlsClass><AcrossNatAcc>false</AcrossNatAcc><NAParentCreditIsUsed>false</NAParentCreditIsUsed><NACreditIsShare>false</NACreditIsShare><NACreditPreferenceList>O</NACreditPreferenceList><NAParentCreditPrc>0</NAParentCreditPrc><NACreditSharedPrc>0</NACreditSharedPrc><AllowOTS>false</AllowOTS><ThirdPLCust>false</ThirdPLCust><ManagedVendID></ManagedVendID><ManagedVendNum>0</ManagedVendNum><NARlsClassCode></NARlsClassCode><DirectDebiting>false</DirectDebiting><ReminderCode></ReminderCode><BitFlag>0</BitFlag><GlbNAParentCreditIsUsed>false</GlbNAParentCreditIsUsed><GlbNACreditIsShare>false</GlbNACreditIsShare><GlbNAParentCreditPrc>0</GlbNAParentCreditPrc><GlbNACreditSharedPrc>0</GlbNACreditSharedPrc><AllowShipTo3>true</AllowShipTo3><OTSSaveAs></OTSSaveAs><CustPartOpts>M</CustPartOpts><HasBank>false</HasBank><PMUID>30</PMUID><DemandCheckForRev>false</DemandCheckForRev><OrderHoldForReview>false</OrderHoldForReview><DemandCheckForRevAction>B</DemandCheckForRevAction><ShipToTerrList>HN</ShipToTerrList><AcctRefNumber></AcctRefNumber><ARInvoiceITCode></ARInvoiceITCode><CreditMemoITCode></CreditMemoITCode><MiscCashRecITCode></MiscCashRecITCode><LegalName>NHÀ THUỐC PHÒNG KHÁM HOÀNG ĐẠT</LegalName><ARInvoiceAdjITCode></ARInvoiceAdjITCode><TaxRegReason></TaxRegReason><InvPerPackLine>false</InvPerPackLine><OrgRegCode></OrgRegCode><DemandCloseRejSkd>false</DemandCloseRejSkd><OurBankCode></OurBankCode><DemandCloseNoMatch>false</DemandCloseNoMatch><DmdCheckPartialShip>false</DmdCheckPartialShip><DmdCheckShipAction>B</DmdCheckShipAction><DemandCheckCUMM>false</DemandCheckCUMM><DemandCheckCUMMAction>B</DemandCheckCUMMAction><DemandPricing>Internal</DemandPricing><PriceTolerance>0</PriceTolerance><PreferredBank></PreferredBank><CheckDateCapPromise>false</CheckDateCapPromise><CheckConfirmCapPromise>false</CheckConfirmCapPromise><CheckUpdateCapPromise>false</CheckUpdateCapPromise><DemandCapPromiseDate>N</DemandCapPromiseDate><DemandCapPromiseAction>B</DemandCapPromiseAction><DemandCapPromiseUpdate>N</DemandCapPromiseUpdate><PeriodicBilling>false</PeriodicBilling><DueDateCriteria>S</DueDateCriteria><PBTerms>0</PBTerms><ERSOrder>false</ERSOrder><DemandSplitSched>false</DemandSplitSched><OTSmartString>false</OTSmartString><DeferredRev>false</DeferredRev><RACode></RACode><DemandCheckConfig>false</DemandCheckConfig><DemandCheckCfgAction></DemandCheckCfgAction><ListCode></ListCode><ShippingQualifierDesc></ShippingQualifierDesc><BillDayDesc>All Days</BillDayDesc><TotOpenInvoices>1</TotOpenInvoices><TotOpenOrders>72</TotOpenOrders><TotOpenPI>0</TotOpenPI><TotInvoiceCredit>19080061</TotInvoiceCredit><TotOrderCredit>201392089</TotOrderCredit><TotPICredit>0</TotPICredit><TotOpenCredit>220472150</TotOpenCredit><TotGlbInvoiceCredit>19080061</TotGlbInvoiceCredit><TotGlbOrderCredit>201392089</TotGlbOrderCredit><TotGlbPICredit>0</TotGlbPICredit><TotGlbOpenCredit>220472150</TotGlbOpenCredit><GlbFlag>false</GlbFlag><ParentCustID></ParentCustID><ParentName></ParentName><PIFlag>false</PIFlag><IntegrationFlag>false</IntegrationFlag><AttrCodeList></AttrCodeList><SendShipment>false</SendShipment><ApplyHoldToOrders>false</ApplyHoldToOrders><FxdTotOrders>72</FxdTotOrders><FxdTotPI>0</FxdTotPI><FxdOrderCredit>201392089</FxdOrderCredit><FxdPICredit>0</FxdPICredit><FxdGlbOrdCredit>201392089</FxdGlbOrdCredit><FxdGlbPICredit>0</FxdGlbPICredit><GlbLink></GlbLink><CustTypeDescription>Customer</CustTypeDescription><BillFreqDescription>Weekly</BillFreqDescription><DiscQualDescription>Add</DiscQualDescription><AddrList>NHA THUOC PHONG KHAM HOANG DAT~Xuân Sơn, Trung Giã~Sóc Sơn~Hà Nội  ~Việt Nam</AddrList><BTAddrList>  ~</BTAddrList><ExtCoExist>false</ExtCoExist><DspFormatStr></DspFormatStr><DspBTFormatStr></DspBTFormatStr><EnableGlobalCust>false</EnableGlobalCust><EnableGlobalLock>false</EnableGlobalLock><PeriodicityDesc></PeriodicityDesc><PeriodicityList>0`Not Used</PeriodicityList><ChargeCodeDesc></ChargeCodeDesc><NAParentCrdAvail>0</NAParentCrdAvail><NAPoolCrdAvail>0</NAPoolCrdAvail><NAChildCrdAvail>0</NAChildCrdAvail><DspRlsClass></DspRlsClass><NAOwnCreditAvail>0</NAOwnCreditAvail><NAOwnCreditUsedDsp>0</NAOwnCreditUsedDsp><NAParentsCreditUsedDsp>0</NAParentsCreditUsedDsp><NASharedCreditUsedDsp>0</NASharedCreditUsedDsp><GlbNAParentsCreditUsedDsp>0</GlbNAParentsCreditUsedDsp><GlbNAOwnCreditUsedDsp>0</GlbNAOwnCreditUsedDsp><GlbNASharedCreditUsedDsp>0</GlbNASharedCreditUsedDsp><GlbNAOwnCreditAvail>0</GlbNAOwnCreditAvail><GlbNAParentCrdAvail>0</GlbNAParentCrdAvail><GlbNAChildCrdAvail>0</GlbNAChildCrdAvail><GlbNAPoolCrdAvail>0</GlbNAPoolCrdAvail><NAPoolCreditUsed>0</NAPoolCreditUsed><GlbNAPoolCreditUsed>0</GlbNAPoolCreditUsed><NACreditUpdated>false</NACreditUpdated><ReminderGroupDesc></ReminderGroupDesc><NACreditCust>false</NACreditCust><NATotalCreditAvail>0</NATotalCreditAvail><NATotalCreditUsed>0</NATotalCreditUsed><BaseCurrCode>VND</BaseCurrCode><TotLCCredit>0</TotLCCredit><TotLCOpenOrders>0</TotLCOpenOrders><TotLCCumInvoices>0</TotLCCumInvoices><TotLCInvoiceBal>0</TotLCInvoiceBal><TotLCUsed>0</TotLCUsed><TotOpenLC>0</TotOpenLC><TotOpenOrderLC>0</TotOpenOrderLC><TotOpenInvoicesLC>0</TotOpenInvoicesLC><InvcOrderCmpDflt>false</InvcOrderCmpDflt><EntityUseCode></EntityUseCode><MXMunicipio></MXMunicipio><OneTimeID></OneTimeID><IsOneTimeCust>false</IsOneTimeCust><CollectionsDate/><Collections>false</Collections><BTLegalName></BTLegalName><PEIdentityDocType>6</PEIdentityDocType><PECollectionAgent>false</PECollectionAgent><PEDocumentID></PEDocumentID><PEGoodsContributor>false</PEGoodsContributor><PENoAddress>false</PENoAddress><PENotFound>false</PENotFound><PEWithholdAgent>false</PEWithholdAgent><PEGuaranteeName></PEGuaranteeName><PEGuaranteeAddress1></PEGuaranteeAddress1><PEGuaranteeAddress2></PEGuaranteeAddress2><PEGuaranteeAddress3></PEGuaranteeAddress3><PEGuaranteeCity></PEGuaranteeCity><PEGuaranteeState></PEGuaranteeState><PEGuaranteeZip></PEGuaranteeZip><PEGuaranteeCountry></PEGuaranteeCountry><PEGuaranteePhoneNum></PEGuaranteePhoneNum><PEGuaranteeTaxID></PEGuaranteeTaxID><COASegReferences></COASegReferences><EInvoice>false</EInvoice><EAddress></EAddress><RegistrationCode></RegistrationCode><CurrencyCurrName>VND</CurrencyCurrName><CurrencyCurrSymbol>VND</CurrencyCurrSymbol><CurrencyCurrDesc>VND</CurrencyCurrDesc><CurrencyCurrencyID>VND</CurrencyCurrencyID><CurrencyDocumentDesc>VND</CurrencyDocumentDesc><CustGrupGroupDesc>Clinic with pharmacy</CustGrupGroupDesc><DeliveryTypeDescription></DeliveryTypeDescription><FOBDescription></FOBDescription><GlobalCurrencyCurrencyID>VND</GlobalCurrencyCurrencyID><GlobalCurrencyDocumentDesc>VND</GlobalCurrencyDocumentDesc><GlobalCurrencyCurrName>VND</GlobalCurrencyCurrName><GlobalCurrencyCurrDesc>VND</GlobalCurrencyCurrDesc><GlobalCurrencyCurrSymbol>VND</GlobalCurrencyCurrSymbol><LanguageDescription></LanguageDescription><MarkUpDescription></MarkUpDescription><PayMethodName>CK/TM</PayMethodName><PayMethodSummarizePerCustomer>false</PayMethodSummarizePerCustomer><PayMethodType>0</PayMethodType><PreferredBankBankName></PreferredBankBankName><PreferredBankDescription></PreferredBankDescription><RASchedCdRADesc></RASchedCdRADesc><ReservePriDescription></ReservePriDescription><SalesRepName></SalesRepName><ShipViaDescription></ShipViaDescription><ShipViaWebDesc></ShipViaWebDesc><TATaxAuthorityDescription></TATaxAuthorityDescription><TaxRegionDescription>Thue GTGT Noi Dia</TaxRegionDescription><TermsDescription>Thanh toán ngay</TermsDescription><TerritoryTerritoryDesc>Hà Nội</TerritoryTerritoryDesc><RowIdent>0x003d018600010000574845524520282850524f47524553535f5245434944203d20000001540008fffb00000000000000000000000000000b2529292000</RowIdent><RowMod></RowMod><DBRowIdent></DBRowIdent></Customer><NAMember><Company>01</Company><RlsClassCode></RlsClassCode><TopCustNum>0</TopCustNum><CustNum>2844</CustNum><TopCustID></TopCustID><Tiered>false</Tiered><TopCustName></TopCustName><RowIdent></RowIdent><RowMod></RowMod><DBRowIdent/></NAMember><ShipTo><Company>01</Company><CustNum>2844</CustNum><ShipToNum></ShipToNum><Name>NHA THUOC PHONG KHAM HOANG DAT</Name><Address1>Xuân Sơn, Trung Giã</Address1><Address2></Address2><Address3>Sóc Sơn</Address3><City>Hà Nội</City><State></State><ZIP></ZIP><Country>Việt Nam</Country><ResaleID>xxxxxxxxxx</ResaleID><SalesRepCode></SalesRepCode><TerritoryID>HN</TerritoryID><ShipViaCode></ShipViaCode><PrimSCon>0</PrimSCon><FaxNum></FaxNum><PhoneNum></PhoneNum><TaxExempt></TaxExempt><EDIShipNum></EDIShipNum><CountryNum>28</CountryNum><LangNameID></LangNameID><BorderCrossing></BorderCrossing><FormatStr></FormatStr><TaxRegionCode>VATD</TaxRegionCode><EMailAddress></EMailAddress><TerritorySelect>SYNC</TerritorySelect><PendingTerritoryID></PendingTerritoryID><CreatedByEDI>false</CreatedByEDI><ExternalID></ExternalID><TaxAuthorityCode></TaxAuthorityCode><GlobalLock>false</GlobalLock><EDICode></EDICode><Character01></Character01><Character02></Character02><Character03></Character03><Character04></Character04><Character05></Character05><Character06></Character06><Character07></Character07><Character08></Character08><Character09></Character09><Character10></Character10><Number01>0</Number01><Number02>0</Number02><Number03>0</Number03><Number04>0</Number04><Number05>0</Number05><Number06>0</Number06><Number07>0</Number07><Number08>0</Number08><Number09>0</Number09><Number10>0</Number10><Number11>0</Number11><Number12>0</Number12><Number13>0</Number13><Number14>0</Number14><Number15>0</Number15><Number16>0</Number16><Number17>0</Number17><Number18>0</Number18><Number19>0</Number19><Number20>0</Number20><Date01/><Date02/><Date03/><Date04/><Date05/><Date06/><Date07/><Date08/><Date09/><Date10/><Date11/><Date12/><Date13/><Date14/><Date15/><Date16/><Date17/><Date18/><Date19/><Date20/><CheckBox01>false</CheckBox01><CheckBox02>false</CheckBox02><CheckBox03>false</CheckBox03><CheckBox04>false</CheckBox04><CheckBox05>false</CheckBox05><CheckBox06>false</CheckBox06><CheckBox07>false</CheckBox07><CheckBox08>false</CheckBox08><CheckBox09>false</CheckBox09><CheckBox10>false</CheckBox10><CheckBox11>false</CheckBox11><CheckBox12>false</CheckBox12><CheckBox13>false</CheckBox13><CheckBox14>false</CheckBox14><CheckBox15>false</CheckBox15><CheckBox16>false</CheckBox16><CheckBox17>false</CheckBox17><CheckBox18>false</CheckBox18><CheckBox19>false</CheckBox19><CheckBox20>false</CheckBox20><ShortChar01></ShortChar01><ShortChar02></ShortChar02><ShortChar03></ShortChar03><ShortChar04></ShortChar04><ShortChar05></ShortChar05><ShortChar06></ShortChar06><ShortChar07></ShortChar07><ShortChar08></ShortChar08><ShortChar09></ShortChar09><ShortChar10></ShortChar10><DemandDeliveryDays>0</DemandDeliveryDays><DemandDateType>S</DemandDateType><DemandAddLeadTime>0</DemandAddLeadTime><DemandAddAction>B</DemandAddAction><DemandChangeLeadTime>0</DemandChangeLeadTime><DemandChangeAction>B</DemandChangeAction><DemandCancelLeadTime>0</DemandCancelLeadTime><DemandCancelAction>B</DemandCancelAction><DemandNewLineLeadTime>0</DemandNewLineLeadTime><DemandNewLineAction>B</DemandNewLineAction><DemandQtyChangeLeadTime>0</DemandQtyChangeLeadTime><DemandQtyChangeAction>B</DemandQtyChangeAction><DemandChangeDateLeadTime>0</DemandChangeDateLeadTime><DemandChangeDateAction>B</DemandChangeDateAction><TradingPartnerName></TradingPartnerName><ResDelivery>false</ResDelivery><SatDelivery>false</SatDelivery><SatPickup>false</SatPickup><Hazmat>false</Hazmat><DocOnly>false</DocOnly><RefNotes></RefNotes><ApplyChrg>false</ApplyChrg><ChrgAmount>0</ChrgAmount><COD>false</COD><CODFreight>false</CODFreight><CODCheck>false</CODCheck><CODAmount>0</CODAmount><GroundType></GroundType><NotifyFlag>false</NotifyFlag><NotifyEMail></NotifyEMail><DeclaredIns>false</DeclaredIns><DeclaredAmt>0</DeclaredAmt><PeriodicityCode>0</PeriodicityCode><ServSignature>false</ServSignature><ServAlert>false</ServAlert><ServHomeDel>false</ServHomeDel><DeliveryType></DeliveryType><ServDeliveryDate/><ServPhone></ServPhone><ServInstruct></ServInstruct><ServRelease>false</ServRelease><ServAuthNum></ServAuthNum><ServRef1></ServRef1><CommercialInvoice>false</CommercialInvoice><ServRef2></ServRef2><ShipExprtDeclartn>false</ShipExprtDeclartn><ServRef3></ServRef3><CertOfOrigin>false</CertOfOrigin><ServRef4></ServRef4><LetterOfInstr>false</LetterOfInstr><ServRef5></ServRef5><HazardousShipment>false</HazardousShipment><OverrideCarrier>false</OverrideCarrier><IntrntlShip>false</IntrntlShip><OverrideService>false</OverrideService><DemandUseCustomerValues>true</DemandUseCustomerValues><TaxRegReason></TaxRegReason><EarlyBuffer>0</EarlyBuffer><OrgRegCode></OrgRegCode><LateBuffer>0</LateBuffer><DemandUnitPriceDiff>false</DemandUnitPriceDiff><DemandUnitPriceDiffAction>B</DemandUnitPriceDiffAction><ExcFromVal>false</ExcFromVal><AddressVal>false</AddressVal><DemandCheckForPart>false</DemandCheckForPart><DemandCheckForPartAction>B</DemandCheckForPartAction><FFID></FFID><FFAddress1></FFAddress1><FFAddress2></FFAddress2><FFCity></FFCity><FFState></FFState><FFZip></FFZip><FFCountry></FFCountry><FFContact></FFContact><FFCompName></FFCompName><FFPhoneNum></FFPhoneNum><ChangedBy>hoangnd</ChangedBy><ChangeDate>2014-03-26T00:00:00</ChangeDate><ChangeTime>34254</ChangeTime><IndividualPackIDs>false</IndividualPackIDs><FFCountryNum>0</FFCountryNum><NonStdPkg>false</NonStdPkg><DeliveryConf>1</DeliveryConf><AddlHdlgFlag>false</AddlHdlgFlag><UPSQuantumView>false</UPSQuantumView><UPSQVShipFromName></UPSQVShipFromName><UPSQVMemo></UPSQVMemo><FFAddress3></FFAddress3><ETCAddrChg>false</ETCAddrChg><SysRowID>9ac2de6d-d796-09ae-e311-5baf4abaabec</SysRowID><SysRevID>140850000</SysRevID><BitFlag>0</BitFlag><IsAlternate>false</IsAlternate><MasterCustNum>0</MasterCustNum><MasterShipToNum></MasterShipToNum><DemandCheckForRev>false</DemandCheckForRev><DemandCheckForRevAction></DemandCheckForRevAction><DemandCheckPartialShip>false</DemandCheckPartialShip><DemandCheckShipAction>B</DemandCheckShipAction><DemandCloseRejSkd>false</DemandCloseRejSkd><DemandPricing></DemandPricing><PriceTolerance>0</PriceTolerance><CheckDateCapPromise>false</CheckDateCapPromise><CheckConfirmCapPromise>false</CheckConfirmCapPromise><CheckUpdateCapPromise>false</CheckUpdateCapPromise><DemandCapPromiseDate></DemandCapPromiseDate><DemandCapPromiseAction></DemandCapPromiseAction><DemandCapPromiseUpdate></DemandCapPromiseUpdate><OTSmartString>false</OTSmartString><LegalName></LegalName><DemandCheckConfig>false</DemandCheckConfig><DemandCheckCfgAction></DemandCheckCfgAction><AddrList>NHA THUOC PHONG KHAM HOANG DAT~Xuân Sơn, Trung Giã~Sóc Sơn~Hà Nội  ~Việt Nam</AddrList><ContactName></ContactName><DspFormatStr></DspFormatStr><TerrSelectFlag>SYNC</TerrSelectFlag><TerritorySelectDescription></TerritorySelectDescription><PeriodicityList>0`Not Used</PeriodicityList><IntegrationFlag>false</IntegrationFlag><GlbLink></GlbLink><GlbFlag>false</GlbFlag><PrimaryShipTo>false</PrimaryShipTo><PeriodicityDesc></PeriodicityDesc><EntityUseCode></EntityUseCode><COASegReferences></COASegReferences><CustNumBTName></CustNumBTName><CustNumCustID>NT00001318</CustNumCustID><CustNumName>NHA THUOC PHONG KHAM HOANG DAT</CustNumName><DeliveryTypeDescription></DeliveryTypeDescription><LanguageDescription></LanguageDescription><MasterCustIDName></MasterCustIDName><MasterCustIDBTName></MasterCustIDBTName><MasterCustIDCustID></MasterCustIDCustID><SalesRepName></SalesRepName><ShipViaDescription></ShipViaDescription><ShipViaWebDesc></ShipViaWebDesc><TATaxAuthorityDescription></TATaxAuthorityDescription><TaxRegionDescription>Thue GTGT Noi Dia</TaxRegionDescription><TerritoryTerritoryDesc>Hà Nội</TerritoryTerritoryDesc><RowIdent>0x003d0d8400010000574845524520282850524f47524553535f5245434944203d20000000e20008fffb0000000000000000000000000000158c29292000</RowIdent><RowMod></RowMod><DBRowIdent/></ShipTo></CustomerDataSet></ds><dsCC><CallContextDataSet><CallContextClient><ClientType>WinClient</ClientType><ProcessId>OMMT1110</ProcessId><AssemblyName>Epicor.Mfg.UI.CustomerEntry</AssemblyName><CustomizationId>3sCustomerForm_1</CustomizationId><CurrentUserId>nguyennk</CurrentUserId><CurrentCompany>01</CurrentCompany><CurrentPlant>MfgSys</CurrentPlant><CGCCode/></CallContextClient><CallContextBpmData><Password/><ButtonValue/><Character01/><Character02/><Character03/><Character04/><Character05/><Character06/><Character07/><Character08/><Character09/><Character10/><Character11/><Character12/><Character13/><Character14/><Character15/><Character16/><Character17/><Character18/><Character19/><Character20/><Number01/><Number02/><Number03/><Number04/><Number05/><Number06/><Number07/><Number08/><Number09/><Number10/><Number11/><Number12/><Number13/><Number14/><Number15/><Number16/><Number17/><Number18/><Number19/><Number20/><Date01/><Date02/><Date03/><Date04/><Date05/><Date06/><Date07/><Date08/><Date09/><Date10/><CheckBox01/><CheckBox02/><CheckBox03/><CheckBox04/><CheckBox05/><CheckBox06/><CheckBox07/><CheckBox08/><CheckBox09/><CheckBox10/><ShortChar01/><ShortChar02/><ShortChar03/><ShortChar04/><ShortChar05/><ShortChar06/><ShortChar07/><ShortChar08/><ShortChar09/><ShortChar10/><RowIdent></RowIdent><RowMod/><DBRowIdent/></CallContextBpmData></CallContextDataSet></dsCC></tns:UpdateRequest></msg:Dta></msg:Req></msg:Body></msg:Msg>
```

My code to read this file

```
 $path='C:/wamp/www/pmc/var/import/customer/Customer.xml';

    $xml=simplexml_load_file($path) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
     //$xmls = file_get_contents($path) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
     echo $xmls;
```

The return is : "Error: can not create object ".
I also tried below code:

```
$path='C:/wamp/www/pmc/var/import/customer/Customer.xml';

    //$xml=simplexml_load_file($path) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
     $xmls = file_get_contents($path) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
     $pos = strpos($xmls, "CustomerDataSet");
       print  $pos;
```

But it shows empty position.

I would like to get data from node "CustomerDataSet" ->"Customer" -> "Company" and "CustomerDataSet"-> "ShipTo" -> "Address1". 
Could someone show what I did wrong ?.

Comment: remove the lline ` or die("Error: Cannot create object");` and what error does it show you?

Comment: Thanks Chris Banks. I change my code to :$path='C:/wamp/www/pmc/var/import/customer/Customer.xml';
   try
        {
   
    $xml=simplexml_load_file($path) ;
  }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {echo $e;}   // --> It shows nothing;

Comment: Did you try the answer I posted?

Comment: better to do `echo $e->getMessage();` to get the actual error message from an exception

Comment: echo $e->getMessage(); did not show any message. But your answer below helps it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the encoding of the XML from this (this is the error you were getting when it wasn't loading):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Because of the namespaces in the XML you need to add some additional parameters to `simplexml_load_string` with the msg namespace and true for the prefix parameter.

Then, use the following to extract the information you need.

```
// if it is a string use this, otherwise use simplexml_load_file
//$sx = simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', 0, 'msg', true);
$sx = simplexml_load_file($path, 'SimpleXMLElement', 0, 'msg', true);
$ns = $sx->getNamespaces(true);
$customerDataSet = $sx->Body->Req->Dta->children($ns['tns'])->UpdateRequest->children('')->ds->CustomerDataSet;
$company = $customerDataSet->Customer->Company;
$address1 = $customerDataSet->ShipTo->Address1;
echo "$company - $address1";
echo "\n";
```

Read more on simplexml_load_string here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

> **Usage**: *SimpleXMLElement simplexml_load_string ( string $data [, string $class_name = "SimpleXMLElement" [, int $options = 0 [, string $ns = "" [, bool $is_prefix = false ]]]] )*

Comment: It worked.  No matter I changed  encoding="utf-16" to encoding="utf-8", It still worked. It worked when  I didn't put "or die("Error: Cannot create object");" into code.  Thanks Chris Banks so much.